# Why is Windows 10 attempting to find this node module from Apache Zeppelin in C:/ instead of the local directory?

Tags: node.js, windows, apache-zeppelin

I am using Apache Zeppelin 0.8.0 to create some software for data visualization. Specifically, I am using the Helium plugin system that Zeppelin provides to create some sharp charts and graphs from High Charts. Using Linux and Mac, I have had no issues getting the visualizations to run-- including the advanced visualizations provided by zeppelin, but they do not work on windows 10 properly. You can test it by [downloading](http://zeppelin.apache.org/download.html) the binary package provided by zeppelin on their home page, install it, run it and then go to the Helium area in the menu--  you will notice the advanced visualizations do not appear (windows 10).

The main issue is with nodejs-- it is trying to find the node module for a package at C:\ instead of the directory where it is being run from-- here is the output:

```
    Running 'npm run bundle --registry=http://registry.npmjs.org/' in C:\Users\Pablo\Desktop\zeppelin-0.8.0-SNAPSHOT\local-repo\helium-bundle

> zeppelin-helium-bundle@ bundle C:\Users\Pablo\Desktop\zeppelin-0.8.0-SNAPSHOT\local-repo\helium-bundle
> node/node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --display-error-details --json

module.js:471
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\node'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
at bootstrap_node.js:509:3

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Users\\Pablo\\Desktop\\zeppelin-0.8.0-SNAPSHOT\\local-repo\\helium-bundle\\node\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Pablo\\Desktop\\zeppelin-0.8.0-SNAPSHOT\\local-repo\\helium-bundle\\node\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "bundle" "--registry=http://registry.npmjs.org/"
npm ERR! node v6.9.1
npm ERR! npm v3.10.8
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! zeppelin-helium-bundle@ bundle: `node/node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --display-error-details --json`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the zeppelin-helium-bundle@ bundle script 'node/node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --display-error-details --json'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the zeppelin-helium-bundle package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR! node/node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --display-error-details --json
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR! npm bugs zeppelin-helium-bundle
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR! npm owner ls zeppelin-helium-bundle
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR! C:\Users\Pablo\Desktop\zeppelin-0.8.0-SNAPSHOT\local-repo\helium-bundle\npm-debug.log
```

And here is the npm-debug.log file:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Users\\Pablo\\Desktop\\zeppelin-0.8.0-SNAPSHOT\\local-repo\\helium-bundle\\node\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\Pablo\\Desktop\\zeppelin-0.8.0-SNAPSHOT\\local-repo\\helium-bundle\\node\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'bundle',
1 verbose cli   '--registry=http://registry.npmjs.org/' ]
2 info using npm@3.10.8
3 info using node@v6.9.1
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebundle', 'bundle', 'postbundle' ]
5 info lifecycle zeppelin-helium-bundle@~prebundle: zeppelin-helium-bundle@
6 silly lifecycle zeppelin-helium-bundle@~prebundle: no script for prebundle, continuing
7 info lifecycle zeppelin-helium-bundle@~bundle: zeppelin-helium-bundle@
8 verbose lifecycle zeppelin-helium-bundle@~bundle: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 verbose lifecycle zeppelin-helium-bundle@~bundle: PATH: C:\Users\Pablo\Desktop\zeppelin-0.8.0-SNAPSHOT\local-repo\helium-bundle\node\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\Pablo\Desktop\zeppelin-0.8.0-SNAPSHOT\local-repo\helium-bundle\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\Pablo\Desktop\zeppelin-0.8.0-SNAPSHOT\local-repo\helium-bundle\node;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\scala\bin;C:\Users\Pablo\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\nodejs;C:\Users\Pablo\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\Heroku\bin;C:\Users\Pablo\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\nodejs;
10 verbose lifecycle zeppelin-helium-bundle@~bundle: CWD: C:\Users\Pablo\Desktop\zeppelin-0.8.0-SNAPSHOT\local-repo\helium-bundle
11 silly lifecycle zeppelin-helium-bundle@~bundle: Args: [ '/d /s /c',
11 silly lifecycle   'node/node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --display-error-details --json' ]
12 silly lifecycle zeppelin-helium-bundle@~bundle: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
13 info lifecycle zeppelin-helium-bundle@~bundle: Failed to exec bundle script
14 verbose stack Error: zeppelin-helium-bundle@ bundle: `node/node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --display-error-details --json`
14 verbose stack Exit status 1
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Pablo\Desktop\zeppelin-0.8.0-SNAPSHOT\local-repo\helium-bundle\node\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:255:16)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Pablo\Desktop\zeppelin-0.8.0-SNAPSHOT\local-repo\helium-bundle\node\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:40:14)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
15 verbose pkgid zeppelin-helium-bundle@
16 verbose cwd C:\Users\Pablo\Desktop\zeppelin-0.8.0-SNAPSHOT\local-repo\helium-bundle
17 error Windows_NT 10.0.14393
18 error argv "C:\\Users\\Pablo\\Desktop\\zeppelin-0.8.0-SNAPSHOT\\local-repo\\helium-bundle\\node\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Pablo\\Desktop\\zeppelin-0.8.0-SNAPSHOT\\local-repo\\helium-bundle\\node\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "bundle" "--registry=http://registry.npmjs.org/"
19 error node v6.9.1
20 error npm  v3.10.8
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error zeppelin-helium-bundle@ bundle: `node/node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --display-error-details --json`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the zeppelin-helium-bundle@ bundle script 'node/node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --display-error-details --json'.
23 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
23 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the zeppelin-helium-bundle package,
23 error not with npm itself.
23 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
23 error     node/node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --display-error-details --json
23 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
23 error     npm bugs zeppelin-helium-bundle
23 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
23 error     npm owner ls zeppelin-helium-bundle
23 error There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I have searched extensively and have attempted reinstalling nodejs on my current system, as well as updating environmental variables. Currently, my theory is that there is an Autorun string somewhere on my machine that is causing it to automatically run/search for this package in C:/, but it is a wild theory. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is a screenshot of my zeppelin helium package page:

[Helium - Zeppelin Windows 10 Issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4V35.png)

Comment: also getting the same issue any solution?